"Single negative" en español
La oración "hay algo" se traduce en inglés como "there is something".
La oración "no hay nada" se traduce en inglés como "there is nothing".
Pero se puede decir "hay nada" o "no hay algo" en español? Y qué significan estas oraciones? Cómo se diferencian a "no hay nada"?

En español, el adverbio negativo "no" es necesario para reforzar palabras negativas que aparecen más adelante en la oración: no es que "no" niegue la palabra negativa, sino que simplemente la refuerza.
Nada bueno ocurrió (Nothing good happened)
No ocurrió nada bueno.
En español también es posible combinar dos o más palabras negativas, por ejemplo pronombres y adverbios:
Nadie hizo nada (Nobody did anything)
Nunca nadie hizo nada (Nobody has ever done anything)
Si deseamos negar la negación, podemos recurrir a construcciones de "que" galicado, por ejemplo:
No es que no haya ocurrido nada (It's not that nothing has happened => Ocurrió algo)
No es que nadie haya hecho nada (It's not that noboby has done anything => Alguien hizo algo)
En respuesta a la pregunta específica, las oraciones:
(*)No hay algo.
(*)Hay nada.
no tienen sentido. Se pueden construir oraciones donde "nada" aparezca antes del verbo (de lo contrario, se hace necesario agregar "no"):
Nada hay que me interese.
No hay nada que me interese. (There is nothing that interests me)
Si "algo" se usa antes del negativo, se traduce como "something (not)", no como "(not) anything".
Algo no ha salido bien. (Something has not worked).
"No" atrae el negativo "nada": No ha salido bien nada.

Simplemente añadir la posibilidad de decir "No hay algo" en oraciones como "¿No hay algo que quieras decirle?" aunque en lugar de algo también se puede decir "nada" (que para no liar mucho, sería mi recomendación personal).

Es verdad. Al igual que en inglés, esa pregunta (en inglés con "something") espera una respuesta positiva: sé o intuyo que hay algo que quieres decirle.

@tac No entiendo a qué te referís con que mi respuesta es un calco y por qué te arrogás el derecho de borrar una respuesta que elaboré con cuidado. Por favor abstenete de volver a hacerlo y, en todo caso, revisá tu respuesta, que tiene más de filosofía que de lingüística.

OK cambio el ejemplo y quizá se entienda mejor:

I have something. -> Tengo algo.
I don't have anything. -> No tengo nada.

Cuál es el patrón que está presente en ambos casos? Exacto, la concordancia. Los determinantes concuerdan con las negaciones, los refuerzan y dan la redundancia necesaria para asegurar la correcta comunicación.
Entonces, la pregunta falla en el sentido de que se piensa que ‘nada’ viene a ser el opuesto exacto de ‘algo’, cuando no siempre se da así. Asimismo, se habla de una ‘negación simple’, como si la sintaxis admitiera las ‘negaciones dobles’ como fórmulas bien formadas del lenguaje. Eso es una regla memotécnica, impulsada sobre todo por autores sajones que intentan demostrar que las lenguas romances son lógicamente inconsistentes; cuando, en realidad, primeramente la simplificación de la doble negación es una regla más de sustitución, que puede o no puede ser aceptada dentro de las normas sintácticas.
No hay ninguna inconsistencia. En realidad, lo único que ocurre es que nunca se entendió cuál es el verdadero sentido de a lo que nos referimos cuando recurrimos al término nada. En efecto, el término no debe entenderse como sinónimo de una ‘carencia’, ‘privación’ o ‘ausencia’. Eso equivale a decir que es posible la actividad cognoscitiva que (valga la redundancia) no refiera a nada; pero desde hace mucho ya sabemos que ‘toda consciencia es consciencia de algo’. Por lo tanto, es imposible concebir algo similar a ‘la nada’, entendiéndola de esta forma. En cambio, el término ‘nada’ debe entenderse como sinónimo de ‘lo indeterminado’, de hecho hay una acepción en el diccionario de la casta que refiere a este sentido.
Finalmente, tus dos inventos (‘no hay algo’ y ‘hay nada’) no son fórmulas bien formadas. Violan las reglas de concordancia, e incluso ni siquiera sé cuál es el sentido en el que deberían entenderse tales afirmaciones. Dejo esta cita, tomada de Introducción a la lógica de Gamut (tengo la versión traducida, en inglés creo que se entiende mejor lo que quiere decir el autor):

Carnap ilustra su posición con ejemplos tomados de un artículo del bien
conocido metafisico Heidegger. En su artículo de 1929, "Was ist Metaphysik" , el filósofo alemán escribe: "Sólo debe ser investigado lo que es, y fuera de esto nada. Pero, ¿qué es nada? ¿Dónde debe buscarse esta nada?". Según Carnap, al formular preguntas tales como ¿Dónde debe buscarse esta nada? estamos siendo engañados por el lenguaje natural. Hay una analogía entre ¿Qué hay afuera? Nieve y ¿Qué hay afuera? Nada. La analogía sólo se consolida por la similitud superficial de las dos oraciones como en There is snow outside y There is nothing outside. Pero el análisis lógico
muestra que, aunque la forma gramatical de las dos oraciones es similar, ambas tienen formas lógicas completamente diferentes. Carnap sostiene que el lenguaje natural es engañoso porque no está claramente defnido y no es lo suficientemente sistemático. Las reglas sintácticas que gobiernan la formación de las oraciones del lenguaje natural no nos permiten distinguír entre afirmaciones y pseudoafirmaciones.

A lo que va el autor es que no tiene sentido decir ‘hay nada’, porque, mirando la estructura, eso ya nos compromete con que hay algo que se tendría que llamar ‘nada’. Por lo tanto, si hay una pregunta que yo sí me hago es acerca de cómo puede ser que en el inglés se admitan cosas como ‘there is something’ y ‘there is nothing’, cuando la segunda afirmación tiene la misma estructura sintáctica pero la estructura lógica y el sentido en el que deben entenderse ambas es completamente diferente?
